# How put the content returned by `db.db.collection` inside` res.json () `?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

In the controller, it searches the `countries` collection for all countries. Inside `db.db.collection ....` I have `console.log (countries)`. It works because the terminal returns me all countries. But `res.json (countries)` doesn't work. On the client side, it returns to me `data: ''`. How can I put the content returned by `return countries` in `res.json()`?

**//controllers/countries**

```
module.exports.read = (req, res) => {     
    const countries = db.db.collection('countries').findOne({}, function (findErr, countries) {
        if (findErr) throw findErr;
        console.log(countries); //it works, in terminal return me all countries

        return countries;
        });

    res.json(countries);
};
```

Comment: Just move the `res.json` next to the `console.log` call where `countries` is available. And don't do `throw findErr` in a callback - instead, send an error response!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of calling a return before an async function has finished. Many people get this wrong. You need to call the "returning" callback in the callback from the db find:

```js
module.exports.read = (req, res) => {     
  db.db.collection('countries').findOne({}, function (findErr, countries) {
    if (findErr) throw findErr;
    console.log(countries); //it works, in terminal return me all countries
    res.json(countries);
  });
};
```